# C: how to initialise a vector

Tags: c, vector, linked-list

I would like to initalise a vector of type

```
struct vector
{
   size_t capacity;
   size_t size;
   int *data;
};
```

I did this but i'm not sure:

```
struct vector *vector_new();
{
   struct vector *vect;
   vect = malloc (1*sizeof(vect));
   vect->capacity = 1;
   vect->size = 0;

   int *data;
   data = malloc (1*sizeof(int));
}
```

I think I need to allocate 2 memory spaces, one that holds the 'struct vector' and one for the data. Should I use malloc() or calloc() ?
Moreover how could I throw an error if there is not enough memory ? Thanks

Comment: Style guide: Don't put spaces around the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators.  They bind very tightly; they should not have spaces around them.

Comment: You could try to read the manual first, then do the same as in that example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc. 

If you check the manual for calloc https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc it will say what makes it different from malloc "Allocates memory for an array of num objects of size size and initializes all bytes in the allocated storage to zero." Which you don't seem to need here. You can also try to read a beginner-level C programming book, which should also have examples.

Comment: Since `vector_new` is the name of a function, you can't dereference it in the body of the function as if it was a pointer to a structure.  You need to allocate a new `struct vector` so you can return a pointer to it.  You need to initialize it.  You didn't attempt to set the `data` element.  You should probably make that a null pointer.  You should review what you mean by capacity and size.  At the moment, it looks like you're lying to yourself about how much data can be stored (the initial capacity is 0 unless you allocate some space).

Comment: There is no mechanism for 'throwing' errors in C.  There are mechanisms of a sort for reporting errors.  For memory allocation failure, returning a null pointer is the traditional technique (and for good reason — it works well, as long as the people calling the allocation functions are disciplined about checking for such failures).  Using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` is usually a bad idea — it is too easy to leak resources and too hard to protect against such leakage.

Comment: I edited my original post please take a look. And yes, for the error I will consider using the errx(); function

Comment: Better, but you have to assign the result of calling `malloc()` to the appropriate places.  You also need to return a value from the function.  If you deal with the assignments and returns, then your vector's initial capacity is indeed 1, with 0 in use.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: `malloc()` returns a value; if you don't save it in a variable, you leak memory.  Always capture the return value from `malloc()` (and `calloc()` and `realloc()`).  Your code doesn't capture the values; therefore, it leaks memory.  You also haven't initialized `vect->data`; things will not go well if you don't.

Comment: But I don't want any data inside this vector as I set my size to 0 ? Edited the post

Comment: @lex you really need to study a bit before asking questions. Basic use of `malloc` etc. is coverd in every C text book.

Comment: @lex `malloc` takes only one argument, `data = malloc (1, sizeof(int));`-> `data = malloc (1 * sizeof(int));`. But allocating memory for a single `int` is rather pointless. You really need to study C from a book or at least from some tutorial, there are tons on the internet.

Comment: Woops at first I wrote calloc but then I suppose there is no need to set every element to 0 that's why I used malloc and forgot to change the syntax. I just want to initalise the data using malloc so that will be able to insert data using other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look somehow like this:

```
#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 10    // initial capacity, choose some appropriate value
                               // between 1 and N

struct vector *vector_new();
{
   struct vector *vect = malloc (sizeof(struct vector));
   vect->capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
   vect->size = 0;
   vect->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * INITIAL_CAPACITY);
   return vect;
}
```

This was the easy part, now you need to write the functions that allow to put some data into the vector, then you'll probably want to use the `realloc` function when the size becomes larger than the capacity.

No error checking is done in this code for brevity.

For error handling you could return `NULL` from the `vector_new` function.

Comment: Yes I see it's very clear. I could check if malloc returns NULL and use the errx() function, this would mean that there is not enough available memory, right ?

Comment: By the way, can I allocate the vect->data using malloc and not put anything in it ?

Comment: @lex exact, `malloc` returns `NULL` if it can't allocate memory (although it is unlikely to happen with small amount of memory on modern computers).

Comment: _Can I allocate the vect->data using malloc and not put anything in it?_: Yes, you can. This is exactly what we are doing here. The allocated memory contains intdetermined values, but as the initial size of the vector is 0, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok thanks. But could you explain this malloc (sizeof(vect)); What is sizeof(vect) at this actual time ? We have just declared vect. I understand sizeof(int) since int is a type. Vect is not a type, it is the name of the variable ?

Comment: @lex sorry, it is a typo, it should be `sizeof(struct vector)` of course.

Comment: Yes. Could we have done sizeof(struct list) for a list ?

Comment: @lex yes of course, if `struct list` has been defined somewhere.